# nodejs alexa skill to continue till the user says stop

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, ask-sdk

I am writing an alexa skill which returns top colleges by city. I want session and the skill to continue till the user says stop. The code for TopCollegesByCityIntentHandler which takes city name is as below:

```
const TopCollegesByCityIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'TopCollegesByCity';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        console.log('handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request', JSON.stringify(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request));
        let speechText = '';
        const cityName = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.cityName.value;

        // logic to get top colleges by city name and modify speechText

        speechText += 'To know top colleges in your city say, top colleges in your city. To stop say, stop.';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Top Colleges', speechText)
            .withShouldEndSession(false)
            .getResponse();
    }
```

But if the user doesn't speak for more than 5-10 seconds, the skill dies by saying "the requested skill did not send a valid response". How do I continue the session till the user says stop ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not keep Alexa's mic open for more than 8 seconds.

However what I would suggest is to use the reprompt method, which would ask a question again if the user doesn't respond within the first 8 seconds.

Here is how it would look like

```
speechText += 'To know top colleges in your city say, top colleges in your city. To stop say, stop.';
repromptText = 'Say top colleges in your city for the city.';
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechText)
        .reprompt(repromptText)
        .withSimpleCard('Top Colleges', speechText)
        .withShouldEndSession(false)
        .getResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here...

- First, I'm not sure why you want to leave the session open. You're not asking a question. (And I'm recommending you don't.)
- Second, if you *do* want to leave the session open you should specify what your `reprompt` will be (*which will automatically leave the session open, no longer need the `withShouldEndSession`*).
- Third, you should put the list of colleges in its own variable and add that to the `SimpleCard`, not the `speechText`. *i.e., no need for the simple card to include the phrase "to stop..."*
- Finally, if you're responding with a long list—which it sounds like you're doing, you want them to know how to stop it or ask for something else **before** you start the list. (Otherwise, they'd have to listen to the whole list before knowing it was possible to stop it.) I'd recommend starting with something like `To know top colleges in your city, say, "Alexa, ask {yourSkillName} for Top Colleges in", and the name of your city. To stop, say "Alexa, stop". Here are the Top Colleges by city: {super long collegeList}`. No `reprompt` (because you don't want the session to remain open). Then you can rely on "one-shot"s to handle your other requests.

[This Alexa design doc](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-design/available.html#design-for-response-time-limits) outlines the 8-second limit.

[Official UserVoice feature request for setting the timeout limit](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/35606791-option-to-eliminate-8-second-time-out-constraint), in case you'd like to add your vote.